# S3 Bucket Types

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

Just wondering if there is a recommended strategy for storing different types of assets/files in separate S3 buckets or just put them all in one bucket? The different types of assets that I have include: static site images, user's profile images, user-generated content like documents, files, and videos.

Comment: Are you serving up the S3 URL's directly or are you using CloudFront as CDN with origin pull from the buckets?

Comment: Also, how are you placing the files into S3 and setting metadata?

Comment: I haven't decided where to serve the URL's up from but I am leaning towards CloudFront.  The site it hosted on Heroku and users will be able to add video via a form with paperclip.  Metadata will be stored in Postgres.

Comment: I meant how are you setting S3 metadata, like key-value pairs for `Content-Type`, `Cache-Control`, etc. that would be sent as headers to requesting clients?

Comment: I am not sure yet, I am just starting to learn about video.  How does this info influence whether I create different bucket types?  If you can shed light on S3 metadata, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as how to group files into buckets. That is really not that critical of an issue unless you want to have different domain names or CNAMEs fordifferent types on content, in which case you would need a separate bucket for each domain name you would want to use.

I would tend to group them by functionality. Perhaps static files used in your application that you have full control over you might deploy into a separate bucket from content that is going to be user generated. Or you might want to have video in a different bucket than images, etc.

To add to my earlier comments about S3 metadata.  It is going to be a critical part of optimizing how you server up content from S3/Cloudfront.

Basically, S3 metadata consists of key-value pairs. So you could have `Content-Type` as a key with a value of `image/jpeg` for example if the file is .jpg. This will automatically send appropriate Content-Type headers corresponding to your values for requests made directly to S3 URL or via Cloudfront.  The same is true of Cache-Control metatags.  You can also use your own custom metatags.  For example, I use a custom metatag named `x-amz-meta-md5` to store an md5 hash of the file. It is used for simple bucket comparisons against content stored in a revision control system, so we don't have to make checksums of each file in the bucket on the fly.  We use this for pushing differential content updates to the buckets (i.e. only push those that have changed).

As far as how revision control goes.  I would HIGHLY recommend using versioned file names. In other words say you have bigimage.jpg and you want to make an update, call it bigimage1.jpg and change your code to reflect this.  Why? Because optimally, you would like to set long expiration time frames in your Cache-Control headers.  Unfortunately, if you then want to deploy a file of the same name and you are using Cloudfront, it becomes problematic to invalidate the edge caching locations.  Whereas if you have a new file name, Cloudfront would just begin to populate the edge nodes and you don't have to worry about invalidating the cache at all.

Similarly for user-produced content, you might want to include an md5 or some other (mostly) unique identifier scheme, so that each video/image can have its own unique filename and place in the cache.

For your reference here is a link to the AWs documentation on setting up streaming in Cloudfront

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingStreamingDistributions.html